# PowerShell error color

Tags: windows-10, powershell, colors

I have put these lines into my Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. (I am using windows 10.)

```
$host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = "DarkCyan"

$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = "Yellow"
```

Error color has changed from red in all cases, except when I run pip to update python modules.
With pip errors the error color is still red. What else should I change in my settings to
make the color change in all cases?
The pip command I am using is this:

```
 pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```

Comment: are those errors coming from PoSh or from python/pip? if the 2nd ... then you will likely need to take a look at what powershell stream is being used.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, the only errors in red come from python/pip.

Comment: then it is unlikely that powershell settings will do anything. _however_, you may be able to find out what powershell stream is carrying the text and then do something with that. take a look at `Get-Help about_Redirection` for info about the various streams.

Comment: You could use some `Try {} Catch {}` logic and output error with `write-host` using `-foreground` parameter and such at this level with the pip commands.